How to prevent user select start date bigger than end date in date picker calender?
I have 2 date picker calendar start date and end date
How can I check and compare when the user select end date must be bigger than start date in oracle apex ?
How to use validation and prevent user select start date bigger than end date
like this code example :
if (:P5_START_DATE > :P5_END_DATE) THEN return error "Start date must be less than end date"



Items are treated as strings, so you'll have to convert them to date datatype values, and then do the comparison.
Create validation that returns error text as e.g.
if to_date(:P5_START_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') > to_date(:P5_END_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') then
   return 'Start date must be less than end date';
end if;

Mind the quotes! Your example shows you used double ones; that won't work in Oracle - strings are enclosed into single quotes.

You're welcome.

one point I received error process validation , I changed the format mask for date fields to YYYY-MM-DD and changed if to_date(:P5_START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') > to_date(:P5_END_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') then error solved

Certainly; TO_DATE's format mask must match value you enter into these items.
